# Passing file contents to outside variable

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm using a FileReader and the HTML file dialog to read a file in my script. How do I pass this file's contents out of the FileReader.onload function?

```
function readFileData(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener
    ('change', readFileData, false);

/* I want to access the contents here */
```

I tried sticking returns in the readFileData and onload functions, but I'm not sure what they return to.

Comment: You want to access the contents in a comment???

Comment: @Musa: Do you genuinely interpret the question that way, or are you just being a jerk?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you know, its `async` and all.

So, the short answer is: No, you can not do that.

However, if you want the contents to be globally accessible for any future calls, you could something like this:-

```
var contents;// declared `contents` outside
function readFileData(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    contents = e.target.result; //<-- I removed the `var` keyword
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFileData, false);

var reasonableTimeToWaitForFileToLoad = 100000;

console.log(contents); //`contents` access first attempt: prints undefined



setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(contents);//`contents` access second attempt: prints the contents 'may be if the time allows.'
}, reasonableTimeToWaitForFileToLoad);
```

Comment: Is there a way to know for sure when the file is loaded? The user is going to upload big files of varying sizes that may take a while to load. Should I just wait until contents is not undefined with a loop?

Comment: No, don't do that. Javascript is single threaded. So, that loop will run forever, till browser crash. Right now, the only way to know the file is loaded is `reader.onload = function(e) {/**here**/}`. You could use `setTimeout` recursively to check whether the file is loaded or not.

Comment: But, IMO, `setTimeout`'s are old fashioned. Design your code that reacts for events. You will be good.

Answer (score 2):

```
var contents;
function readFileData(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
   contents = e.target.result;
  }

 reader.readAsText(file);

 reader.onloadend=function(e) {
   console.log(contents)
 }
}  

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFileData, false);
```

Comment: You must explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue.  When you're declaring contents within the onload, it's no longer available after that function has run.  You need to declare contents outside of that scope first.

```
var contents;
function readFileData(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
   contents = e.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener
    ('change', readFileData, false);

//make changes here
//contents should have the correct value
```

Comment: this absolutely will not work as the FileReader is async.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to realize that reading a file with a `FileReader` is an asynchronous task, and you cannot work with it in a synchronous manner.

There are many ways to handle this, but many of them are not suited for recommendations ;)

I would do it one of these 2 ways:

1: you can call a function from within the onload event handler and pass the file contents as a parameter

2: you can trigger an event from within the onload event handler and pass the file contents as event data

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `contents` outside both functions and assign to it inside the inner function:

```
var contents;
var outer_fn = function() {
  var inner_fn = function() {
    contents = '42';
  }
  inner_fn();
}
outer_fn();
// here, `contents' is '42'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar challenge and this is what I used to solve the issue.

```
var contents;
function readFileData(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
   contents = e.target.result;
  }

 reader.readAsText(file);

 //calling to access the 'contents' variable
 accessFileContents();
}  

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFileData, false);
var wait4file2load = 1000;

/* To access 'contents' here */
function accessFileContents(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(contents);
  }, wait4file2load);
}
```

It won't give `undefined` value since we are calling it after the file is completely uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Angular 7 (typescript), and this is how I solved my problem.

What I wanted to do was to access the base64 conversion that was happening inside fileReader -> reader.onload

Then pass that parameter to another method where I could convert it to a JSON object then post it to the API seeing I want to post another parameter as well in the post. (not added in this code)

What I did first was to declare what I potentially needed to access outside the Method that.

```
base: any = null;
base64File: any = null;
fileToTest: any = null;
```

Then I converted the pdf to base64 when the upload event fired

```
convertToBase64 (e){

  this.fileToTest = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => { 
        this.base64File = reader.result.slice(28); 
};

reader.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('Error: ', error);

}.bind(this.base64File);

reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToTest);

return this.base64File;
}
```

Finally access the base64 file in the other method

```
 onSubmit() {

  console.log("base 64 file is visible", this.base64File);

    var base = 
      {
        "FileBase64": this.base64File,
        "Path": "document",
        "FileType": ".pdf"
      };

  console.log("JSON object visible", base);
  this.uploadService.base64Post(base);
}
```

Everything works now, and hopefully maybe this can help someone else finding themselves with the same problem.

Using Angular 7, code is in the component file, and the post function is in the Service file. Without my comments the code is exactly like this in the component file.